# With JSON - How to serialize the Account's Shipping and Billing Address?

Tags: json, serialize

I want to serialize just the Address object (lets call it an object) of Account (and Contact as well)

Is there a way to access the ShippingAddress/BillingAddress of the account using the JSON.serialize method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Address information is surfaced in two ways on these objects...

- **Address Fields.** Using the historic standard set of fields on the source object (e.g. [Account](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) or [Contact](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)). Where XXX is Shipping or Billing, the standard set of fields are XXXCity, XXXCountry, XXXCountryCode, XXXPostalCode, XXXState, XXXStateCode, XXXStreet. These fields are available via SOAP/REST API and from within Apex.
- **Address Compound Type.** And now also through a new [Address Compound Type](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/compound_fields_address.htm) (new to Spring'14 in Beta). This does in fact give you a single object/data type that wraps all the address fields. It however is only available read-only and then only through the Salesforce SOAP/REST API's, and not via Apex.

> Standard addresses—addresses built into standard objects in Salesforce—are accessible in the SOAP and REST APIs as an Address, a structured compound data type, as well as individual address elements.
>   
>   So if you are within Apex you will have to develop your own Apex data type and serialise that. I have developed a native [Apex Address type here](https://gist.github.com/afawcett/9345047). To use it, it's a simple as calling it's **valueOf** method.

```
    // Query Account and approprite fields
    Account myAccount = 
        [select Id, 
            BillingCity, 
            BillingCountry, 
            BillingPostalCode, 
            BillingState, 
            BillingStreet 
         from Account
         where Name = 'Burlington Textiles Corp of America' limit 1];

    // Create a Billing Address
    Address billingAddress = 
        Address.valueOf(myAccount, Address.AccountAddress.Billing);

    // Serialise it via JSON
    String jsonBillingAddress = JSON.serialize(billingAddress);
    System.debug(jsonBillingAddress);
```

This outputs...

> 11:35:55.344 (344137285)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|{"Street":"525 S. Lexington Ave","StateCode":null,"State":"NC","PostalCode":"27215","CountryCode":null,"Country":"USA","City":"Burlington"}

**NOTE:** The Address type also supports the State and Country pick list feature if enabled in the org.